# Is there any reason to encrypt a VM? (already have file vault encryption for Mac enabled)

Tags: encryption, virtual-machine

I currently have File Vault enabled for encryption on my Mac. Is there any need to encrypt a virtual machine that is installed on my Mac? Or does the File Vault cover that?

I am running Mac OS Sierra 10.12 (Host), and using Virtual Box for my VM's. The guest OS is Ubuntu 14.04. If someone got access to my Mac that is protected by File Vault, would they have any way of accessing my Ubuntu VM?

Comment: I think this is getting downvoted because a good deal more context is required. For example, what virtualisation provider and guest operating system are you using, what threats do you want to protect against, and how paranoid do you want to be?

Comment: It probably also depends what's on that VM.

Comment: Welcome! This seems to be opinion based, and therefore might be off topic here. See: [help/on-topic] | [mcve] | [ask] | [help].

Comment: @manannan Sorry about that, I should have definitely added more context. Running latest Mac OS Sierra 10.12 & Virtual Box with an Ubuntu 14.04 installation. The question was already answered however, so I don't think this info helps now. Thanks! (I'll be better about this with future questions)

Comment: Perfectly valid question for SuperUser or Security stacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @manannan mentioned, it is not easy to give you a proper answer to your question given the little context you provided. But I'll give it a try - feel free to edit your question and I'll update the answer.

With File Vault activated on your Mac, every file that is written to the encrypted disk will be encrypted. A virtual machine consists of one or more virtual disks which are stored on the Mac's file system. Hence they are encrypted on your Mac and can't be read by someone who disassembles your Mac and tries to read your hard disk.

If you export the virtual disk file (for a example on a non-encrypted USB flash storage), the virtual machine is no longer encrypted - so for a safe transfer to another user, you have to come up with your own encryption.

Having the virtual machine encrypt the disk "again" would enable you to safely export and transfer your disk image to another user but would also add overhead to using the machine, as the virtualized OS would have to take care of encryption on top of File Vault.

For a customer project which handled very sensitive data we once created a virtual machine inside a TrueCrypt encrypted folder on the Mac. Like that you basically get the same effect as having the virtualized OS encrypted its hard disks - but I think that TrueCrypt is no longer actively maintained and I don't know any alternative product.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for answering! Was very thorough and answered my question exactly. Thank you! I'll be better about adding extra context in the future.